# Simulate infection report

Tags: python

I'm having an issue where the answer I'm getting is 1 number off of the answer that is expected. I can't figure out why.

> In TODO 5, you will implement the simulate_infection function. The function has the following three parameters:
>
> - population: An int specifying the total population of the animals.
> - initial_infected: An int specifying the number of animals infected on day 1.
> - r_number: A float specifying the rate of spread of the infection (R number).
>
> Based on the provided arguments, the function will print one or more lines, each of which displays two values - day number (starting from one) and current alive population - separated by a space.
>
> Let us go over the details of how the function works using the following example arguments:
>
> ```
> population: 1000000
> initial_infected: 1000
> r_number: 1.1
> ```
>
> Overall, the simulate_infection function implements the loop that prints the state of the population each day. Note that the first row should show the full population, i.e., before any of the animals die. The last row should show 0. There should be exactly one row showing 0.
>
> We suggest you implement the function in the following flow:
>
> Assign two variables - one for the number of animals that are currently infected (e.g., infected), and the other for the number of animals that are already deceased (e.g., deceased). Using the example arguments the initial assignment would be 1000 for the infected and 0 for the deceased.
>
> Print the day number (1), and the state of the population on the first day.
>
> The state of the population can be computed as population - deceased (total deceased animals subtracted from the population). Hence, the first row in our specific case would be:
>
> 1 1000000
>
> ## the population is still unaffected on day 1
>
> ## there are infected animals but none of them died just yet
>
> Define a loop that executes as long as there are any animals left by checking the state of the population. (Note that different solutions are possible. Calculating the total deceased and subtracting it from the population as a state of population (without changing the population) can be a solution. Alternatively, the deceased can be used for only the animals that get deceased for that day. In this case, the population can be decreased every day.) It depends how you manipulate the population and deceased variables.
>
> Within each iteration:
>
> Update the total number of deceased animals (deceased + infected).
>
> Update the number of currently infected animals (infected * r_number). Note that only a whole number of animals can be infected. Hence, you have to use rounding. Always round up, i.e., 4.1 -> 5, 78.7 -> 79, etc. (consider the built-in functions such as round or ceil method from the math library. Consider different cases when choosing the function to use.)
>
> Increment the day number by 1.
>
> Print the day number, and the state of the populations on that day.
>
> For example, we get the following lines for:
>
> Day 2:
>
> ```
> 2 999000
> # 1000000 - 1000
> # deceased is set to 1000
> # infected is set to 1000 * 1.1 = 1100
> ```
>
> Day 3:
>
> ```
> 3 997900
> # 999000 - 1100
> # deceased is set to 2100
> # infected is set to 1100 * 1.1 = 1210
> ```
>
> Day 4:
>
> ```
> 4 996690
> # 997900 - 1210
> # deceased is set to 3310
> # infected is set to 1210 * 1.1 = 1331
> ```
>
> Day 5:
>
> ```
> 5 995359
> # 996690 - 1331
> # deceased is set to 4641
> # infected is set to 1331 * 1.1 = 1464.1 -> 1465 (rounding up)
> ```
>
> Day ... (etc.)
>
> You are encouraged to validate your implementation by placing a call to the simulate_infection as shown below:
>
> ```
> simulate_infection(1000000, 1000, 1.1)
> ```
>
> The expected output of running the file would then be:
>
> ```
> 1 1000000
> 2 999000 
> 3 997900 
> ...
> 48 123944
> 49 35312
> 50 0
> ```

Here is the code I have so far.

```
def simulate_infection(population, initial_infected, r_number):
    infected = initial_infected
    deceased = 0
    day = 1
    lastpopulation = population
    print(day, population)
    while lastpopulation >= 0:
        deceased += infected
        infected = round(infected * r_number)
        day += 1
        lastpopulation = population - deceased
        print(day, lastpopulation)
```

Here is the 'error' im getting:

> The expected output to the provided arguments (322802, 13, 1.7300982536113874) is not matching. At line 3 the reference answer is `'3 322766'`. Your implementation of `simulate_infection` prints `'3 322767'`.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? For example, have you [stepped through the code to examine the variables](/q/4929251/4518341)? Or do you know [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)? If this is homework, see also [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). If we were to help with debugging this whole thing, we'd need to see the description of what it's supposed to be doing, to make sure it matches.

Comment: the platform I'm having to use for class is expecting +1 to the last population number.

Comment: `lastpopulation = population - deceased` in the loop rather than `lastpopulation = lastpopulation - deceased` looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `infected = round(infected * r_number)` statement. The [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#round) function returns the nearest integer to its input (which might be smaller or larger). Instead, you probably always want the ceil of that number (if someone is partially infected then he's in fact infected!!). Replace that instruction with `math.ceil(infected * r_number)`:

```
import math

def simulate_infection(population, initial_infected, r_number):
    infected = initial_infected
    deceased = 0
    day = 1
    lastpopulation = population
    print(day, population)
    while lastpopulation >= 0:
        deceased += infected
        infected = math.ceil(infected * r_number)
        day += 1
        lastpopulation = population - deceased
        print(day, lastpopulation)
```

Output:

```
1 322802
2 322789
3 322766
...
```